# Sabre API - ICE Security System: 606

Tags: rest, soap, authentication, sabre

I received the credentials to start developing with Sabre (IPCC, Password, Sign-in, and TA) but I am unable to create a session.

It gives me the error "ICE security system: 606"

I found this on https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_basics/status_codes_and_errors

> USG_SECURITY_ICE_ERROR
>
> Internal
>
> The client application needs to stop processing for at least 500
>   milliseconds before attempting to retry the message.

But there was nothing with "606" beside it, so I don't know if that's the correct message or not. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

USG_SECURITY_ICE_ERROR can occur for a lot of reasons, in particular, for the error code 606 it means that the user you were trying to use has not been provisioned with necessary accesses.

If that user was given by Sabre, I recommend you to contact the help desk so they can engage the corresponding team. If it was created by the agency and you want to use it, please contact your account executive in order for them to request the access.